# Syntax error: missing semicolon

Tags: mysql, sql

A mensagem de erro Syntax error: missing semicolon está aparecendo no meu END IF, mais especificamente somente o IF fica sublinhado com vermelho:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE cadastraEleitor(IN nome VARCHAR(100),dataNasc DATE)
BEGIN
    IF ( (SELECT (year(curdate())) - (SELECT (year(dataNasc)))) < 16) THEN
        SELECT ('INDIVIDUO NAO PODE VOTAR - 16');
    ELSE    
        INSERT INTO eleitor VALUES (NULL,nome,dataNasc);
    END IF

END 
$ DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Achei a solução, apenas um ; depois do END IF - `END IF;`